# Find nth occurrence of groups of thousands which sum to a given number in lexical order

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, recursive-algorithms

A large number can be comma formatted to read more easily into groups of three. E.g. `1050 = 1,050` and `10200 = 10,200`.

The sum of each of these groups of three would be:

`1050=1,050` gives: `1+50=51`

`10200=10,200` gives: `10+200=210`

I need to search for matches in the sum of the groups of threes.

Namely, if I am searching for `1234`, then I am looking for numbers whose sum of threes `= 1234`.

The smallest match is `235,999` since

`235+999=1234`. No other integer less than `235,999` gives a sum of threes equal to 1234.

The next smallest match is `236,998` since `236+998=1234`.

One can add 999 each time, but this fails after reaching 999 since an extra digit of 1 is added to the number due to overflow in the 999.

> More generally, I am asking for the solutions (smallest to highest) to:
>
> a+b+c+d… = x
>
> where a,b,c,d… is an arbitrary number of integers between 0-999 and x
>   is a fixed integer

Note there are infinite solutions to this for any positive integer x.

Given a solution a, how would one find out how many smaller solutions exist?

for example, for the solution:

236,998

there exists only one smaller solution as before, namely, 235,999

But for a large solution to 1234 such as the huge number:

50,100,198,302,100,220,030,134,100

it could take years to compute the number of previous solutions via computer loops from smallest numbers until one finally reaches this number.

is there some kind of mathematical formula to calculate how many smaller solutions there are for a given solution?

so for the above number:

50,100,198,302,100,220,030,134,100

exactly how many smaller solutions are there which also give a sum of threes = 1234?

Comment: you can confirm the number is greater than 20 just by a setbinop call in PARI GP.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee asking for exact number of solutions smaller than a given solution

Comment: yeah but you can use logic to cut down brute force a lot, all values for 1234 need the following :  an even number of odd parts,  parts that are $n$ mod 3 greater than $-n$ mod 3 by $n$ mod 3 amount for some non-zero remainder $n$, etc.

Comment: Here is some technical details to think about:

- number of odd parts is determined by the parity of the sum.
- any permutation doesn't change solution status ( just how large the number is potentially). 
- any padding using 000 doesn't change solution status

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee very good points

Comment: and that's not even invoking pigeonhole principle. it says any solution with two parts has a part at least 617, three parts 412, four parts 309, five parts 247, six parts 206, seven parts 176, eight parts 155, and nine parts 138.

Answer (score 1):

Possible partial algorithm ideas:

- induce partitions of partitions so 235,999 represents 1,235,998 as well as 1,234,999 etc.
- add parity matched parts , and average those parts out ... ex. 
  237,997 and 235,999 averaging parts gives you 236,998 (now it doesn't always work out, only when parts are increasing in one part matched with  same amount of decreasing in the other for starters)
- use permutations
- use addition of own parts 50,100,198,302,100,220,030,134,100 generates 150,198,302,100,220,030,134,100 for example.
- use averaging own parts( same parity matters for a whole number answer but carry halves onto other values perhaps ) 150,198,302,100,220,030,134,100 produces 174,174,302,100,220,030,134,100 as an example.
- probably many more.